# Interpret the content of the UI as a image

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, bitmap, ocr

I am developing an application which is talking to a legacy application. My application must be able to know the status of the legacy application, and able to read the signs in the lower right corner of the legacy application. The problem is that all the information in the window is rendered as a bitmap image, so I cannot use the Windows API to read the text in the window.

I'm thinking of using OCR to interpret the information in the window. But I just need information about 4 chars located at the bottom right of the window, and when I have to read this data regularly, it feels a bit overkill.

It's always the same font, but the characters can be scaled depending on the size of the window.

Is there a simple and quick method to convert bitmaps information to the letters?

Hear are two examples with small and big scale.
[image: small scale]
[image: big scale]

What I am interested in:

- The first two chars (can be AF, NP, CH, OF, LI, CO, SC or WI)
- The number (can be 1-5)
- The direction of the arrow (can be right, up, left or down)
- The color of the chars (can be 16 different colors)
- (The two numbers after the arrow is x and y of the mouse, and is not interesting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't have too many different characters, you can create a database of sub-images that you are searching for.
For example you take a snapshot of your legacy application, and crop the image around the "SC". 
Then at regular intervals you search for that template, and all the others that you have created. It works better and faster when you know *where* to search, which might be your case.

However I must say that this approach is not robust to window scaling. But you can probably force-rescale it to a predefined dimension.

The art is called "**screen scraping**".
I use AHK and its function ImageSearch for fast development. http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm

OCR is not that overkill, You can give a try to GOCR http://jocr.sourceforge.net/ .

Answer (score 1):

if the position of the data you are interested in is always the same you could probably get away with just comparing pixels to a couple of temlpate images (if you know the window size and the resulting scale of the image can probably even generate matching templates on the fly). This might even be quite fast, because the character sequences for example are different enough that you'll be able to identify a sequence by looking at a single row of pixels.